Log4j2 configuration for Java application using Log4j2.properties file
I have an ETL application that runs every hour through a task scheduler. Whenever the ETL app starts the logfile needs to be generated named as ETL_LOG_<CURRENT_DATE_AND_TIMESTAMP>.log. The file needs to be rolled over once it reaches the size limit of 20MB and the filename containing the CURRENT_DATE_AND_TIMESTAMP should remain constant for all the rollovers having indexing at the end such
filename created at the beginning
ETL_LOG_06_AUG_2024_034816.log
The rolled over filenames
ETL_LOG_06_AUG_2024_034816-1.log
ETL_LOG_06_AUG_2024_034816-2.log
...
ETL_LOG_06_AUG_2024_034816-7.log
Even after few minutes or hours the DATE_AND_TIMESTAMP which was set initially should remain constant over all the rolled-over files
such as after 2 hours filename should be like
ETL_LOG_06_AUG_2024_034816-12.log (No change in date and time, only index gets updated)
once the ETL application is about to complete or terminate, all the files which were created as part of the application runup should be compressed in a zip file named as ETL_LOG_ZIP_<DATE_AND_TIMESTAMP>.zip
again, the date and timestamp should be the same as set initially for the logfile for example:
ETL_LOG_ZIP_06_AUG_2024_034816.zip
NOTE: the task scheduler wouldn't create an instance or trigger the application until the last runup is completed or terminated.
I want to do it using the property configuration with log4j2
below is my property file
# Set root logger to output only ERROR and FATAL events to stdout, serverlogs, and MiscLogEvents appenders
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, FILE

# Log files location
property.basePath = ../../
log4j.configurationFile=${basePath}/FortuneApp/codebase/log4j2.properties

# RollingFileAppender name, pattern, path and rollover policy
appenders = fortune

appender.fortune.type = RollingFile
appender.fortune.name = fortune
#appender.fortune.fileName= ${sys:logFileName}.log
appender.fortune.fileName= ${sys:logFileName}.log

# Below properties are for compressing files into a .zip format.
# appender.fortune.filePattern= ${basePath}/logs/app_%d{ddMMyyyy'_'HHmmss}.log.zip
appender.fortune.filePattern= ${sys:logFileName}-%i.log.zip
appender.fortune.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.fortune.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}{${timeZone}} %-5p [%t] %c - %m%ex%n
appender.fortune.policies.type = Policies

# RollingFileAppender rotation policy
appender.fortune.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.fortune.policies.size.size = 2KB
appender.fortune.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
# appender.fortune.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
# appender.fortune.policies.time.interval = 1
# appender.fortune.policies.time.modulate = true

# Delete all files older than ND days
#appender.fortune.strategy.action.type = Delete
#appender.fortune.strategy.action.basepath = ${basePath}/FortuneApp/logsCollection/interfaces/logs
#appender.fortune.strategy.action.maxdepth = 2
#appender.fortune.strategy.action.condition.type = IfLastModified
#appender.fortune.strategy.action.condition.age = 2D

# Configure root logger
rootLogger.level = ERROR
rootLogger.appenderRef.fortune.ref = fortune

# loggers = fortune,execution,service,extraction,transformation
loggers = fortune,execution,common,extraction,service

logger.fortune.name = org.fortune
logger.fortune.level = INFO

# logger.execution.name = org.fortune.execution
# logger.execution.level = INFO
 
#logger.common.name=org.fortune.common
#logger.common.level = INFO
 
#logger.extraction.name=org.fortune.extraction
#logger.extraction.level = DEBUG
 
#logger.execution.name=com.fortune.execution
#logger.execution.level = DEBUG
 
#logger.service.name=com.fortune.service
#logger.service.level = ALL

Class file
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder;

import org.fortune.common.utilityProps;

public class FortuneLoggerUtility {

    private static String logFileName = null;
    private static String log4j2PropertyFileLocation ;

    static {
        
        logFileName = utilityProps.BASE_PATH + utilityProps.getProperty("LogFileLocation") + "ETL_LOG";
        
        log4j2PropertyFileLocation = utilityProps.BASE_PATH+File.separator+"FortuneApp"+File.separator+"codebase"+File.separator+"log4j2.properties";
        
        System.out.println("LogFileName : " + logFileName);

        System.out.println("Log4j2 Property File Location : " + log4j2PropertyFileLocation);
        
        prepareFile();
    }

    protected FortuneLoggerUtility() {
        
    }
    
    public static void prepareFile() {

        String dateAndTimeString = getCurrentTimeStamp();       
        String logFile = logFileName + "_" + dateAndTimeString;
        
        //Read and load Log4J2 Properties File
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            
            System.out.println("log4j2 Properties filepath = "+log4j2PropertyFileLocation);
            
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(log4j2PropertyFileLocation) );

            // Update properties for dynamic values
            System.setProperty("logFileName", logFile);
                        
            //Creating Configuration Builder to read the Configuration from provided properties file
            PropertiesConfigurationBuilder builder = new PropertiesConfigurationBuilder();
            
            //setting root properties as given in the properties file to ConfigurationBuilder
            builder.setRootProperties(properties);
            
            //Initializing Configuration
            Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    

    public static Logger InitializeLogger(Class<?> classname) {

        return LogManager.getLogger(classname);
    }

    public static String getCurrentTimeStamp() {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMMyyyy_HHmmss");
        return LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter).toUpperCase();
    }
}

the above code is resolving my first problem of keeping the name constant over all the rolled-over log files but still each rolled-over file is getting created as
ETL_LOG_06_AUG_2024_034816-1.log.zip
ETL_LOG_06_AUG_2024_034816-2.log.zip
ETL_LOG_06_AUG_2024_034816-3.log.zip
instead of creating a zip and putting all the files with same date and timestamp
Also please suggest the best possible way to do it using only the properties change instead of creating custom file appender or programmatic configuration.
I am expecting a solution that can adapt to properties change directly and doesn't require many changes on the class file.
